# How to make Selenium wait until an event occurs, or until a variable takes a value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i use selenium to complete the form in a part of the form, I have two text boxes that I complete with the codes below

```
username='something'         #In the initial state, they do not have a value
password=something               #In the initial state, they do not have a value

input_username=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value="//input[@id='username_txt']")
input_username.click()
input_username.send_keys(username)



input_password=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value="//input[@id='password_txt']")
input_password.click()
input_password.send_keys(password)
```

How can I make Selenium wait for the values of **username** and **pass** (to be generated through another function) I don't know how to generate **username** and **pass** How long does it take

In other words, I want to tell Selenium, whenever the value for two variables comes, enter them into the text boxes and wait until then and don't close the browser.

Comment: first generate username password and then run selenium code

Comment: username password It may take time to generate it, and it may even generate different usernames and passwords during the execution of Selenium. My program wants to try every username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put the method(s) generating the username and the password before sending the text into the input elements. Something like the following:

```py
username = generate_username()
password = generate_password()
# generate_username() and generate_password() are methods you need to implement

input_username=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value="//input[@id='username_txt']")
input_username.click()
input_username.send_keys(username)



input_password=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,value="//input[@id='password_txt']")
input_password.click()
input_password.send_keys(password)
```

We can also help with implementing the `generate_username()` and `generate_password()` methods if you can provide the requirements for their outputs.

Comment: Thank you for your time, the values username and password are produced when the program is running. Is it possible to use your suggested method like this?

Comment: Sure, it possible. This is the way things normally done